# Confused about Hoka - 外 or 他

Tags: word-choice, words

Can someone help me. I have seen a few different translations for this word, including other place,the rest and another. I also saw two kanji. Are there two different meanings?

Comment: Your question will be much improved if you can include some sentences you have seen or context. Also, your prior research you did before you asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

他 is the kanji you want to use, the other one appears to be usable with the same meaning according to the dictionary, but I have never seen it used as such. 外 is almost only used for the meaning of outside.

hoka basically means other. It can be used in many ways, but always comes down to the same basic meaning.

他の人 the other person.
その他は？ Anything else?
その他(sometimes read そのた)literally means "others". Especially the category "others" on websites etc.